# Prove that an uncountable subset of a second countable space contains at least one limit point

Tags: general-topology

This is a 2 part problem about second countable space.

i)Prove that the set of all isolated points of a second countable space is countable

Definition: $x$ is an isolated point if ${x}$ is open in the topology.

Since the topology is second countable, the set of basis is countable and open sets are defined to be unions of sets in the basis. Thus if x is an isolated point, then x is part of the basis set. Now if there are an uncountable number of isolated points, they are all basis elements, so we would have an uncountable number of basis elements.

(ii) Hence, show that any uncountable subset A of a second countable space contains at least one point which is a limit point of A.

Suppose A does not contain any point that is a limit point. Since the space is second countable, we have a countable basis set $B_i$, $i \in N$ such that their union is the entire space X. Since A is a subset of X, each point of A must be contained in some $B_i$ and each $B_i$ is open. Now I'm not sure if this is correct, but since A is uncountable and we only have countable number of $B_i$, is it the case that one of the $B_i$ must contain an uncountable number of points of A. I think that part is accurate. But how do I go from here to showing that every basis elements that contains points of A all contain another point of A that they all have in common, which would be the limit point of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to (i), you are right: if $X$ is second countable, as witnessed by a countable base $\{B_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ of $X$, than for any isolated point $x$, by the definition of a base there should be a basic set $B_n$ such that $x \in B_n \subseteq \{x\}$ and it follows that $\{x\}=B_n$ is in the base to start with. All singletons of isolated points are members of *any* base for the space. As there *is* a countable base, there cannot be more than countably many isolated points.

If then $A$ is an uncountable subset, $A$ itself is a second countable space when given the subspace topology, so $\textrm{Isol}(A)$ (the (relatively) isolated points of $A$) is at most countable by $(i)$ and so $A\setminus \textrm{Isol}(A)$ is uncountable (or $A$ would have been countable, which it is not) and all points in it are by definition limit points of $A$ that (bonus!) are even members of $A$ themselves (there can be many limit points outside as well).

Comment: I just took a look a Munkres' text to make sure I'm not confusing the definition of isolated points in topology and analysis. So Munkres does define it as a singleton that is open. That is the same as saying an isolated point is just  a point that is not a limit point right? So the analysis and topology definitions are still the same (as long as we dont bring up sequence).

Comment: by the way, is there a reason why topology texts do not define isolated points the same way it is defined in analysis? in analysis: x in the subset A is an isolated point if there is an open neighbourhood does not intersect A at any other point versus in topology: x is an isolated point if {x} is open . I can't think of any cases where the definition disagree.

Comment: Also one area that causes some confusion is how limits points are not defined in terms of the space but as the subset versus isolated points. So take an example in (R, T) the reals with euclidean topology, the set (0,3) U {4}. In topology, 0 and 3 would considered limit points of the subset  (0,3) U {4}, but {4} is not an isolated point of the subset because {4} is not an interval so it is not open. However if we zoom into the subspace topology , then {4} would be open so it is an isolated point, but then the points 0 and 3 do not exist in this subspace topology.

Comment: @willyx888 we never use just “isolated point”, but it’s really always “isolated point of $A$” and it always means that $\{x\}$ is open in $A$.  Or equivalently, there is an open set $O$ such that $O \cap A =\{x\}$.

Comment: ok i went back and reread all the definitions, it make sense now

Answer (score 1):

(ii) is an entierly trivial consquence of (i).  If there is no limit point then every point is isolated and there are only countable number of them. But then $A$ is countable, a contradiction.

Comment: oh right! of course

Comment: one small point, when we are talking about a subset of a space that is second countable, are we talking about the subspace topology induced by the subset?

Comment: Yes, we are talking about the subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

If no point of $A$ was a limit point of $A$, then every point of $A$ would be an isolated point, and therefore $A$ would be countable.